# Java site won't load all components when using FQDN URL, but works when using server name URL

Tags: java, url, fqdn

I'm trying to access a Java web application using the fully qualified domain name. It accesses the site, but loads only some components, **excluding** the help and login menus.

However, if I replace the FQDN with the server name, it loads everything.

a) http://fully-qualified-domain-name.example.co.nz/home
This **DOESN'T** work.

b) http://server-name/home
This **DOES** work.

Points to note:

1) The symptoms mimic those of "potentially unsafe components" being blocked, however no warning pops up for this despite being enabled in the Java Control Panel.
2) I have added the site to browser security exclusions. No difference with or without.
3) I have the correct JRE installed.
4) No proxy server is being used.

Comment: Have you checked your hosts file (assuming you are in Windows) to see if the domain name mapping is done correctly? Also, are you running things in admin mode?

Comment: Yeah, probably a local issue at the vendor's end. Thanks for your assistance.